# Can't copy folders with Laravel Mix

Tags: webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

i have a project using **Laravel 5.4** and **Laravel Mix**, and i have an images folder where some of the images have the same name but a different category, as such they are contained within a diferent directory.

So

```
resources/
  assets/
    images/
      globalimage.png
      versiona/
        image1.png
        image2.png
      versionb/
        image1.png
        image2.png
```

What i need is the **copy** command in Laravel Mix to copy these folders as well as any files within them so that my public folder has the same folder structure.

How can i do this?

```
mix.js('resources/assets/backend/js/main.js', 'public/backend/js')
   .js('resources/assets/frontend/js/main.js', 'public/frontend/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/backend/sass/main.scss', 'public/backend/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/frontend/sass/main.scss', 'public/frontend/css')
   .sourceMaps()
   .copy( 'resources/assets/backend/images/**/*', 'public/backend/images/' )
   .copy( 'resources/assets/frontend/images/**/*', 'public/frontend/images/' )
   .version()
   .disableNotifications();
```

This is my current **Mix** config file the part i need to change is those **copy commands**

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out, there's a third parameter to the **copy** command which is a boolean which specifies whether or not to flatten the folder structure, if you set it to false it'll copy everything with it's folder structure intact.

So my Mix config became

```
   .copy( 'resources/assets/backend/images/', 'public/backend/images/' )
   .copy( 'resources/assets/frontend/images/', 'public/frontend/images/', false )
```

And that worked just fine

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [copyDirectory function](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#copying-files-and-directories), if you want to maintain the directory structure.

`mix.copyDirectory('resources/assets/fonts', 'public/fonts');`