# Laravel Mix - is it possible to copy a directory (without flattening) and exclude certain filetypes?

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

Working with Mix 6 on a templating project - I'm trying to set up a workflow where an internal directory gets copied / compiled into a finished theme, and I've hit a sticking point.

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
internal
  modules
    slideshow
      slideshow.html
      slideshow.js
      slideshow.json
      slideshow.scss
      image.jpg
theme
  modules
```

In *internal*, all module `js` and `scss` get compiled into separate files, but all other files should get copied to the matching module directory in *theme*. The end result should be:

```
internal
  modules
    slideshow
      slideshow.html
      slideshow.js
      slideshow.json
      slideshow.scss
      image.jpg
theme
  modules
    slideshow
      slideshow.html
      slideshow.json
      image.jpg
```

According to the [mix documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/copying-files), the only way to copy files and preserve directory structure is with:

`mix.copy( 'internal/modules', 'theme/modules' );`

using an explicit directory reference, but this copies the `js` and `scss` as well. I can copy with exclusion using something like `internal/modules/**/!(*.scss|*.js)` for the first argument, but any use of wildcards flattens the directory structure - which won't work for (hopefully) obvious reasons.

Mix doesn't seem to provide a way to exclude filetypes without flattening directory structure, nor does it provide a way to cherry-pick those files back out after they've been copied. Previous versions of Mix have [provided a 3rd argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477271/cant-copy-folders-with-laravel-mix) to toggle directory flattening - e.g. `mix.copy( from, to, false )` - but that no longer seems to work in Mix 6.

I've also considered setting a webpack exclusion [along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059366/how-to-exclude-directory-from-getting-bundled-by-webpack), but I wasn't able to ignore `scss` and `js` in modules without also preventing them from being compiled at all.

Does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish selective directory copying using Mix? Open to additional packages / shortcuts, but can't switch off Mix for this one. I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Ran into the same issue just now. I'd like to keep the directory structure but exclude certain filetypes using `mix.copy`